# How to get image or video from CAROUSEL_ALBUM instagram api?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get first image/video (if its not possible get media_url) from a carousel album so i added `children{media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url}` but its not working. Also, i would like to know if its possible to get more than 1 recent_media (following documentation to get recent_media only gets 1)

```
from define_insta import getCreds,makeApiCall

def hashtagMedia(params):
    endpointParams = dict()
    endpointParams['user_id'] = params['instagram_account_id']
    endpointParams['fields'] = 'id,children{media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url},caption,comment_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink'
    endpointParams['access_token'] = params['access_token']
    url = params['endpoint_base'] +'/'+ params['hashtag_id']+'/'+params['type']
    print (url)
    return makeApiCall(url,endpointParams,params['debug'])



print ("\n ------------ Recents -------------\n")
params['type'] ='recent_media'
hashtagRecentpMediaResponse = hashtagMedia(params)
for post in hashtagRecentpMediaResponse['json_data']['data']:
    print ("\nlink to post: ")
    print (post['permalink'])
    print("\n Children:")
    print(post['children'])
    print ("\nPost Caption: ")
    print (post['caption'])
    print ("\nMedia type: ")
    print (post['media_type'])
    print ("\nMedia Url: ")
    print (post['media_url'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you get an error in the API response? If so, can you share here? Does this happen for all or only some queries?

Comment: From [IG Media docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media) => "The media_url field will be omitted from responses if the IG Media contains copyrighted material or has been flagged for a copyright violation."